# .htaccess rewrite rule not submitting post form data?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, .htaccess, post

htacccess rewrite URL rule without .php extension and also some URL with category name as parameter I have successfully done both but after this my post form method is not working I need help here is my code of .htacess and form

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite extensionless URLs to .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]


RewriteBase /






# Redirect requests for category URLs to category.php with the category parameter
RewriteRule ^collections/([^/]+)/?$ collections/category.php?category=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^categories/([^/]+)/?$ categories/category_url.php?category=$1 [L]



## EXPIRES CACHING ## <IfModule mod_expires.c> ExpiresActive On ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 day" ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 day" ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 day" ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 day" ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 day" ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 dya" ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 day" ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 day" ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 day" ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days" </IfModule> 

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

here is a formn code

```
<form action="/update_cart" method="POST"> 
                        
                        <input type="hidden" name="p_sku" value="<?php echo $pro['sku']; ?>"></form>
```

also with the ajax request

```
xhr.open('POST', '/update_cart', true);
```

I have tried to update URL in action form you can see in the form action attribute